# Nest custom JSP tag inside JSTL <c:out>

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:out value="${jsDirectory}javascript/StoreCommonUtilities.<tag:versionnumber/>js"/>"></script>
```

Where `<tag:versionnumber/>` is a custom JSP tag that works on its own. Currently, it just literally prints out `"<tag:versionnumber/>"`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You said that it's a "custom JSTL tag" which isn't making any sense. It's a "custom JSP tag". To learn what JSTL really is, head to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<c:out>` is used to escape special HTML characters (`<`, `>`, `&`, `'` and `"`). I sure hope you don't have those characters in the `jsDirectory` attribute. So there's no reason to use `<c:out>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jsDirectory}javascript/StoreCommonUtilities.<tag:versionnumber/>js"></script>
```

That said, if you want to use the value of `<tag:versionnumber>` in other tag attributes, you should create an EL function instead of a tag, or make it possible to store the result in a page-scope attribute, as `<c:set>` does:

```
<tag:versionnumber var="version"/>
<c:out value="${version}"/>
```

Comment: Noted should be that `<c:out>` is mandatory in JSP 1.x, when EL wasn't supported in template text. But JSP 2.0 is over a decade old already, so I'd really be surprised if one would still  use JSP 1.x these days :)